# WPF form locking up with background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.5

I am developing an in-house backup program that utilizes .NET 4.5's `ZipArchive` and `ZipFile` classes. So far I have successfully been able to zip up folders of varying sizes and contents, but when a large folder is being zipped the UI freezes until all backups are completed. I've been looking all over google and SO to try to find a solution but so far no luck.

Here is my call to start the background thread:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        var result = BackupFolder(b1.Tag.ToString(), b1.Name);
        Log = result.Result ? new BackupLog(string.Format("Finished zipping '{0}.zip'", b1.Name)) : new BackupLog(string.Format("Error zipping '{0}.zip'", b1.Name));
    }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

And here is the method it is calling:

```
private async Task<bool> BackupFolder(string path, string folderName)
{
    try
    {
        var zipPath = string.Format("{0}{1}.zip", _backupPath.Backslash(), folderName);
        Log = new BackupLog(string.Format("Starting zipping '{0}.zip'", folderName));
        if (File.Exists(zipPath)) // ZIP already exists, let's update the contents
        {
            using (var existingZip = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(existingZip, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                    {
                        if (archive.Entries.Any(a => a.FullName.Equals(Path.GetFileName(file)))) // Check if current file exists in the ZIP
                        {
                            var zipArchiveEntry =
                                archive.Entries.First(a => a.FullName.Equals(Path.GetFileName(file)));

                            if (zipArchiveEntry != null) zipArchiveEntry.Delete(); // Remove existing file from ZIP
                        }
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else // ZIP does not exist, let's create it
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, zipPath);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debugger.Break();       
    }
    return await Task.FromResult(false);
}
```

I have tried using `Task.Run()`, creating a `BackgroundWorker` and probably a couple other things that I've forgotten to try to get the UI to remain interactive while it is zipping in the background.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `result.Result`, never combine asnyc/await and `.Result` or `.Wait()`. Also, the only `await` I see in your async function is `await Task.FromResult(true);` or ` await Task.FromResult(false);` which does nothing for you. No code is running on a background thread. Also `Dispatcher.Invoke` puts code on the UI thread, it just waits a while before putting it there.

Comment: Thanks for the info Scott. I've done threading in the past with WinForms but WPF is a little more confusing. I am going to take another crack at it tomorrow; my brain tired of looking at code today.

Comment: Get rid of all the async/await stuff, get rid of the dispacter, then just do `var result = await Task.Run(() => BackupFolder(b1.Tag.ToString(), b1.Name);` and mark the calling function `async`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `BackupFolder()` method is "AINO": `async` in name only. The `async` keyword exists to change the semantics of a method so that it can use the `await` keyword. The only place you use `await`, you are "waiting" on a `Task` object that is *initialized* in the completed state. There's no actual asynchronous waiting going on.

At the same time, you are using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` to execute the method. That means you are explicitly instructing the framework to execute your method in the UI thread. This, combined with the fact that your `BackupFolder()` method isn't *actually* asynchronous means that you are blocking the UI thread for the duration of the operation.

To fix your code, change `BackupFolder()` back to being a simple synchronous method:

```
private bool BackupFolder(string path, string folderName)
{
    .
    .
    .
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debugger.Break();       
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then instead of calling `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, just run the synchronous `BackupFolder()` method in its own `Task`:

```
string path = b1.Tag.ToString(), folderName = b1.Name;
bool result = await Task.Run(() => BackupFolder(path, folderName));
```

Note:

- I am being conservative in the above, and assuming that the `b1` object, whatever it is, is *not* thread-safe. Thus, I've added local variables which are used to capture the current values from the `b1` object, so that those values can be safely passed to the `BackupFolder()` method when it's finally executed in the task thread.
- Naturally, using the `await` operator here will require that the method containing that call be marked `async`. That may in turn require the caller of *that* method to be marked `async`, and so on. That's how it is with `async`.

Comment: Thanks this worked out nicely. I was making it out to be much more complicated than it actually was.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Dispatcher.Invoke(...);` or `InvokeAsync` does not run anything in background thread. Exactly the opposite is purpose of Dispatcher class - to schedule work on UI thread.

Second, you are using async/await incorrectly. Only what's inside Task will run in background thread:

```
await DoSomething();

async Task DoSomething(){
   Trace.WriteLine("This is still in UI thread")
   await Task.Run(...); //action inside task will run asynchronously
   Trace.WriteLine("This is UI thread again");
}
```

so your code can look like this:

```
//this is UI thread
bool result = await Task.Run(() => BackupFolder(b1.Tag.ToString(), b1.Name"));
//this is UI thread again

private bool BackupFolder(string path, string folderName){
   //this is background thread, since it is invoked from Task;   
}
```